# How to set up Eclipse for FPGA design in VHDL and Verilog)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vhdl, verilog, fpga

I am new with Eclipse, I have used it for SW development and in Altra environment for Nios processor. But now, I have a pretty large project that I have to manage and I would like to use Eclipse to have all the files in the system to make it easier to manage and update.

The project has multiple directories for various IPs and has multiple targets for ASCI, Xilinx and Altera FPGAs. In a near future the project will support both NIOS, Microblaze and ARM processors and I would really like to keep the whole project in one Eclipse project file if possible. I have tried several different options, but nothing seems to work properly.

I am looking for some freeware and not commercial programs like Sigasi.

Thanks in advance,
Farhad

---

This is an update to let others know about my progress.

Well, I finally managed to get it to work.

- I installed the latest version of [Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Main_Page) on my PC
- Installed  version 6 of Java (the only one I could get to work)
- Installed the latest version of the [VEditor](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/veditor) into Eclipse.
- Mounted the Linux project directory as my P disk on PC
- created a new project in Eclipse and linked it to the one on the P drive.

It took some time to figure this out, but it now works perfectly.

Comment: I only know about ["DVT Eclipse"](http://www.thinkverification.com/reviews/38-dvt-eclipse-for-systemverilogspecman-code-developers.html) for Specan, Verilog, and VHDL, but that plugin isn't free.  I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I don't think I can justify a commercial license at the moment. It is just a 'good to have' thing.

Comment: Yeah.  That's why I haven't tried it either.

Comment: Segasi does have a free version http://www.sigasi.com/sigasi-starter-edition

Comment: Try looking here: http://www.vhdleditor.com/vhdl-ides

Answer (score 6):

These are the ones I know of:

- Veditor (beta) - http://sourceforge.net/projects/veditor/
- sigasi free    - http://www.sigasi.com/sigasi-starter-edition
- signs (no longer in development)         - http://sourceforge.net/projects/signs/
- zamiaCAD (replacement of signs) - http://zamiacad.sourceforge.net/web/